# What is the sound source at the beggining of music: (Tina Turner - Sarvesham Svastir Bhavatu)

Tags: sound-design, music

I would like to know what is the source of the music: [Tina Turner - Sarvesham Svastir Bhavatu (0:02sec)](https://youtu.be/6XP-f7wPM0A) is it instrumental or is it produced with electronics. How can I produce it to include it in my own music?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this would at best fit on  https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/ It is not about sound design but identifying a sound source.

Comment: This is also two questions in one, they should be separated.